# Displaying invalid attribute before type cast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model with date attribute. I built a custom validation using [attribute]_before_type_cast so that a date like '31.02.2013' make validation failing.

The problem is that:

```
@invoice.order_date = '31.02.2013'
@invoice.order_date #=> Sun Mar 03 00:00:00 +0100 2013
```

So on the view layer user gets message about invalid date but the invalid attribute is automatically changed to 03.03.2013 which is infact a proper date so it is kind of non-sense.

Is there a way to stop that type_cast and display that attribute with invalid date?

Comment: what's the point of marking it as invalid if it actually works?

Comment: Validation works. However user sees the error message about invalid date but the date in a text field is correct. Due to Ruby date convertion mechanism.

Comment: If you use an invalid date, RAILS has a tendency to coerce that invalid date into a valid date, which can really mess up data storage processes and regulatory compliance in a number of industries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a custom setter method to prevent the changing of the attribute.

```
def order_date=(date)
  date = your_validate_and_format_method(date)
  self.send(:write_attribute, :order_date, date)
end
```

In the `your_validate_and_format_method` you can do something like validate, format and you can determine to keep the old value or use the new one.